# Informatica Expression IIF

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have this set of codes in my Informatica expression

```
IIF(V_TR = 'TT'
OR
V_TR = 'TV'
OR
V_TR = 'VC'
OR
V_TR = 'TI'
OR
V_TR = 'TL'
OR
V_TR = 'NC'
OR
V_TR = 'CE'
OR
V_TR = 'D1'
OR
V_TR = 'DM'
OR
V_TR = 'N1'
OR
V_TR = 'NA'
OR
V_TR= 'U1'
OR
V_TR = 'UA', 'Y', 'N')
```

I know what the code means but what exactly does it do in the expression? DOes it serve as a filter to filter out all these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more context of what the expression and business needs of the expression it will be impossible to give more than guesses.

The 2 main ideas I can think of are:

1. The Y or N value are used later in a filter transform
2. The Y or N value is the desired output value based upon the input ports given the expression.

Comment: Yes, it actually leads to a function which takes Y or N to further process the business logic. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the input port gets any of the value in OR clause it will return 'Y' else 'N'.